# How to forward SSH agent connection to unqualified hostnames by default?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

I have a number of local domains in my resolv.conf search order. I would very much like to forward SSH agent by default when I connect to an unqualified (without DNS suffix) hostname. The best I've been able to come up with is something like the following in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *.edu
    ForwardAgent no
Host *.com
    ForwardAgent no
Host *.net
    ForwardAgent no
Host *.org
    ForwardAgent no
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Along with listing known suffixes for edu/com/net/org that I do still want to forward to, such as .srv.example.com.

For a site that has a host naming prefix convention (such as fc-* for fedora systems), a simple wildcard entry matches them, but that doesn't work for generic or non-prefixed names.

Is there any better way to do this than the above ugly hack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple:

```
Host *.*
   ForwardAgent no

Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
```

The first line basically matches everything containing at least one `.` and since the first match counts, the broader patter in the next line never gets evaluated. Obviously, you would put specific hosts above all this.

Comment: Wish I could give you extra points for finding something so blazingly obvious in retrospect. Thank you!